# If i add subscribe in service and unit test of that service, i'm getting Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Subscription'?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, subscription, subscribe

This is my service

**my-service.service.ts**

```
export class MyService {
    constructor(public http: HttpClient) {}

    createChatRecord (data, id) {
        let logData = {"hist" : data , "uid": id };
        let headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers = headers.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
        let options = { headers: headers };

        return this.http.post(MY_URL, logData, options)
            .subscribe(res => res);

    }
}
```

This is my spec file for the above service

**my-service.spec.ts**

```
it("It should post", () => {
        myservice.createChatRecord(mockData, mockId)
            .subscribe((data: any) => {
            expect(data).toBe(null);
        });
    const mockReq = httpMock.expectOne(MY_URL);
    expect(mockReq.request.method).toBe("POST");
    mockReq.flush(null);
    httpMock.verify();
});
```

If i add subscribe in spec file, i'm getting this error. 
**Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Subscription'**. But if i remove subscribe in service, it is not showing that error.

I need to use subscribe in my service. How can i test this post call without this error ?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You incorrectly have the `subscribe()` usage in your service class. If you remove that usage you will get rid of that error.

```js
createChatRecord (data, id) {
    let logData = {"hist" : data , "uid": id };
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
    let options = { headers: headers };

    return this.http.post(MY_URL, logData, options);

}
```

Comment: but if i remove that subscribe, it is not making network call. Is it wrong to add subscribe in service?

Comment: Yes it is incorrect to do that. The network request will be made when the `subscribe()` method is called. You need to have a subscription in your unit test to test that and in your code where you are calling `createChatRecord(...)` you will also need to subscribe there as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you please update your answer with a sample snippet or something so that it will be more clear for me?

Comment: Have you stepped through the Angular tutorial to see how to do this? They do a great job of showing how to set up and use a service like you are creating, showing you how to do this. Here is the specific step in the tutorial that details how to do this: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel suggested, i removed subscribe from service and i added service in the method where i'm calling createChatRecord.

**My function where it calls createChatRecord**

```
myfunction() { // To make call record in service now 
    this.servicenow.createChatRecord(this.conversationData, this.userId)
    .subscribe();
}
```

**myservice.service.ts**

```
 createChatRecord (data, id) {
        let logData = {"hist" : data , "uid": id };
        let headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers = headers.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
        let options = { headers: headers };

        return this.http.post(MY_URL, logData, options);

    }
```

So i learnt that If i subscribe in the service, it will return a Subscription and not Observable, and that's why I got this error.